# wierd behavior 2 viewlist same activity

Tags: android

I'm using the following codes. I don't know why, but the second viewList gets a gone appearance, even if I did not modify it. I have no idea how to solve it.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
</ListView>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
</ListView>
```

---

```
onCreate(){
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dual);
    lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    lv2 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView2);
    lv1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , adsGenerator()));        
    lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {                
            getItem = arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString();          
            lv2.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,adsGenerator2(getItem) ));
        }
    });
```

}

Comment: Have you tried assigning an orientation to the `LinearLayout`? 
`android:orientation="vertical"`

Comment: thanks for the replay, but i think i did not make myself clear.my problem is: the second panel is looking lighter, i almost cant read. it is appearing like a gone visibility, and i havent set it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the lists side-by-side: Give both ListViews `android:layout_width="0dp"`

If you want them one on top of the other: Give both ListViews `android:layout_height="0dp"` and give the LinearLayout `android:orientation="vertical"`

EDIT: Also, you should never use `wrap_content` for the height of a ListView. Use `match_parent` or have it set using layout_weight.

Comment: thanks for the replay, but i think i did not make myself clear.

Comment: my problem is: the second panel is looking lighter, i almost cant read. it is appearing like a gone visibility, and i havent set it.

Comment: Maybe post some screenshots and/or post some code from your adapters.